# I need a code to do blank validation on my guestbook

Tags: python, html

Hey Guys I am working on a website and I've added a guestbook to my website it is working and running on google appspot but there is a problem. It allows people to submit blank content. I need a code to tell the user that this submission is not valid. I will share my code and any helps would be much appreciated. That's my first coding experience and my first website.
I put an if statement but it does not work. Thanks for helping out guys.

```
import os
import urllib
import jinja2
import webapp2


from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb



JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
autoescape=True)

DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'default_guestbook'


def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)


class Author(ndb.Model): 
    identity = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)


class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)



class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greetings_query = Greeting.query(
            ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_values = {
            'user': user,
            'greetings': greetings,
            'guestbook_name': urllib.quote_plus(guestbook_name),
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
        }

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = Author(
                    identity=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
                    email=users.get_current_user().email())

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        greeting.put()
        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')

        if greeting:
            greeting.put()
            self.redirect('/')
        else:
            self.redirect('/?error=That seems invalid to me.')

        query_params = {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}
        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/sign', Guestbook), ], debug=True)
```

Comment: you can add require attribute to html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the content for emptiness, not the `greeting` itself, and do it before putting potentially empty greeting to the storage:

```
content = self.request.get('content')
if content:
    greeting.content = content
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/')
else:
    self.redirect('/?error=That seems invalid to me.')
```

or make an on-page javascript inspection, as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp), or use some lib, like [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if the content is empty or not.

instead, you are checking if the greeting object is there or not.  CHange the if condition as follows

```
if users.get_current_user():
    greeting.author = Author(
            identity=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
            email=users.get_current_user().email())

    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')

    if len(greeting.content > 0):
        greeting.put()
        self.redirect('/')
    else:
        self.redirect('/?error=That seems invalid to me.')

    query_params = {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}
    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))
```